# Can you make a filepicker upload public on S3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, filepicker.io, filepicker

I'd like the files I upload to S3 with Filepicker.io to be public. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can either make the bucket itself publicly accessible:

[image]

or grant permissions to everyone on a specific subfolder/object of your s3 Bucket by adding the following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:**",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/public/*"
        }
    ]
}
```